# how to use Lctrl+tab using AHK on 2nd keyboard using intercept?

Tags: autohotkey, intercept

I want to implement a basic command of Lctrl+tab and remap my PageUp key on the 2nd keyboard and use it as above, but after brainstorming I am not able to do it.

the ways I tried :

```
pgdn::Send, ^{Tab}

pgdn::Send, ^Tab

pgdn::Send, ^+Tab
```

All these don't work. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by:

1. Replugging my keyboard to a different port and reinstalling AutoHotkey.
2. After this removed old keys from intercept and added new ones (it was un-necessary).
3. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

`PgDn::Send {LControl Down}{Tab}{LControl Up}`

Comment: not working, does keyboard manufacture matters? are the commands case sensitive? is it necessary to put + to bind commands together? :/